# ¿Cómo regresar a la pantalla principal en un navigation drawer?

Tags: android

soy nuevo en android y quisiera saber como puedo regresar a la pantalla principal en un navigation drawer, por que cuando entro en un fragment y quiero regresar a la pantalla principal me salgo de la aplicación. He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, new MainActivity()).commit();
```

pero me sale un error

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, lo que tienes que hacer es sobre-escribir el metodo cuando presionas hacias atras:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1){
    finish();
   }
   else {
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

Luego de verificar si tienes un Fragment puedes o terminar la aplicacion o remover el fragment